# Create a new Repo with the local cloned copy alone

Tags: git

Unfortunately my GIT Repo server is down indefinitely..

I just have a local clone copy which is assumed to be the latest, having all commits and branches.

Now. How do i create a new Bare repo out of this Clone copy.

I dont want to turn this copy in to a git repo. Instead , is there a way to make a new repo out of just with the .git folder. A bare repo to be specific

Answer (score -1):

A bare repo really **is** just one that has no working directory.
I am pretty sure if you simply delete all the working files you will have what you need.

It is the git database that stores all the details required to 'reconstruct' any commit state.